# input three strings into function, function needs to return the longest substring that is in all three strings

Tags: c, substring, nested-loops, c-strings, function-definition

I have written the code already, and its pretty much finished, but while testing it, it would sometimes faulter(very rarely), and I cant quite figure out why.(Input three strings into function, function needs to return the longest substring that is in all three strings).

```
 char* findSubstring(char* string1, char* string2, char* string3) {
    int pointer = 0;
    int length = 1;
    char *temp1;
    char* temp2;

    
    for (int i = 0; string1[i]; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; string2[j]; j++) {

                    for (int k = 0; string3[k]; k++) {

                        if (string1[i] == string2[j] && string3[k] == string1[i]) {

                            if (strspn(&string1[i], string2) > length && strspn(&string1[i], string2) == strspn(&string2[j], string3)) {
                                length = strspn(&string1[i], strinh2);
                                pointer = i;


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
    
    temp1 = (char*)malloc(length * sizeof(char) + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        temp1[i] = string1[pointer + i];
        
    }
    temp1[length] = '\0';

    return temp1;
   
}
```

So this is the function, and again it works most of the time, but here and there it just throws out something random that is nowhere near the expected outcome.So if someone can see what i can improve on i would appreciate it.

Example of the code not working:

Input:

string1:  isdbhfjdfklekrumpirisbgozuesbgbzu

string2:   rgekrumpirasz954ho8g

string3:  juidfg7808h5840870ghghkrumpirizg78jue56780jgeo8579h9krumpir

expected outcome is "krumpir", i get "is".

Comment: You need to define "here and there" in more technical terms. Example input?

Comment: @tadman yes of course here it is:   string1:   isdbhfjdfklekrumpirisbgozuesbgbzu

string2: rgekrumpirasz954ho8g

string3 juidfg7808h5840870ghghkrumpirizg78jue56780jgeo8579h9krumpir

Comment: @tadman not letting me tzpe im sry im new to then site, the outcome should be "krumpir" and its actaually "is".

Comment: The `strspn` function doesn't look for matching substrings, so I don't think it's useful for solving this problem. You'll need to write a function that takes two string pointers, and the two starting indexes into those strings. The function should compare characters one at time to find the length of the matching substring starting from those indexes.

Comment: @user3386109 that's the thing, the  code works just fine for most of the inputs, if it didn't I would probably not even post this here, kinda hurts throwing it away considering.

Comment: @AllanWind it would be possible with strstr() maybe, but i would need to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: `strstr` is not useful for this either

Comment: Yup, the thing with `strspn` is that the second argument is just a list of characters to look for. So `strspn("hello", "leehhll")` will return 4, since the first 4 letters of `hello` are all found in `leehhll`. That doesn't help you at all. So you just need to write your own `strmatch` function that actually does what you want.

Comment: @user3386109 didn't know that about strspn, damn. You would think the code would work way less times then no?

Comment: Yeah, I would think that it would be easier to find non-working examples than working examples.

Comment: @user3386109 must've gone to easy with the test cases, anyways thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious problems:

- strspn is wrong for this -- it finds a prefix of its first argument that consists of characters from anywhere in the second argument.  So `strspn("abcd", "ecab") == 3` even though the strings are completely different.  You'll need to write a longest prefix match function (it does not exist in the stdlib.)  Something like:

  ```
    int prefix_match(const char *a, const char *b) {
        int i = 0;
        while (a[i] && a[i] == b[i]) ++i;
        return i; }
  ```
- when comparing string1 with string2 and string3, you require the matches to be the same length, but you should be considering the minimum of the two match lengths.  This causes you to not match `krumpir` (your expected result) as string1 and string3 both contain `krumpiri` but string2 does not.

combining those, you end up with a loop like

```
for (int i = 0; string1[i]; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; string2[j]; ++j)
        for (int k = 0; string3[k]; ++k) {
            int l2 = prefix_match(&string1[i], &string2[j]);
            int l3 = prefix_match(&string1[i], &string3[k]);
            if (min(l2, l3) > length) {
                length = min(l2, l3);
                pointer = i; } }
```

This can be optimized better (for example, hoisting `l2` out of the innermost loop and skipping it entirely when `l2 <= length`), but should work.

Answer (score 1):

As the passed strings are not changed within the function then the function parameters should be defined with qualifier `const` as for example

```
char * findSubstring( const char *s1, const char *s2, const char *s3 );
```

As for your code then the function `strspn` does not do what you think.
According to the C STandard (7.23.5.6 The strspn function)

> 2 The strspn function computes the length of the maximum initial
> segment of the string pointed to by s1 which consists entirely of
> characters from the string pointed to by s2.

That means for example if you call

```
strspn( "ababccab", "cba" );
```

then the function will return the length of the first string though the first string is not equal to the second string.

Using your approach with nested for loops the function can be defined for example the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * findSubstring( const char *s1, const char *s2, const char *s3 )
{
    size_t length = 0;
    size_t pos = 0;

    size_t n1 = strlen( s1 );
    size_t n2 = strlen( s2 );
    size_t n3 = strlen( s3 );

    for (size_t i = 0; i + length < n1; ++i)
    {
        int found = 1;

        for (const char *p2 = s2; 
             found && ( p2 = strchr( p2, s1[i] ) ) != NULL && p2 - s2 < n2 - length;
             ++p2)
        {
            for (const char *p3 = s3; 
                 found = ( p3 = strchr( p3, s1[i] ) ) != NULL && p3 - s3 < n3 - length; 
                 ++p3)
            {
                size_t n = 1;
                
                while (s1[i + n] == p2[n] && p2[n] == p3[n]) ++n;

                if (length < n)
                {
                    length = n;
                    pos = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    char *result = malloc( length + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = s1[pos + i];
        }

        result[length] = '\0';
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s1 = "isdbhfjdfklekrumpirisbgozuesbgbzu";
    const char *s2 = "rgekrumpirasz954ho8g";
    const char *s3 = "juidfg7808h5840870ghghkrumpirizg78jue56780jgeo8579h9krumpir";

    char *s = findSubstring( s1, s2, s3 );

    if ( s != NULL ) puts( s );

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
krumpir
```

Comment: how important is it to add "unsigned" in front of char? Would it work without?

Comment: also isnt this incomplete: char *result = malloc( length + 1 );?

Comment: @HelpMe where do you see `unsigned`?

Comment: @HelpMe no - `sizeof(char)` is by definition (it comes from the C standard) `1`

Comment: also i found another input that doesn't work on it, but it is definitely way better then what i had originally. if you are interested in checking it out i will send it

Comment: @0___________ sorry i'm not myself, const is what i meant

Comment: @HelpMe As sizeof( char ) by definition in the C Standard is equal to 1 then this line malloc( length + 1 ) is equivalent to malloc( ( length + 1 ) * sizeof( char )  ). But using sizeof( char ) is redundant in this context.

Comment: also my bad, i was given faulty examples, where the said expected outcome isn't correct, the code works perfectly

Comment: @HelpMe As I wrote as the strings are not changed within the function then parameters should be declared with the qualifier const.

Comment: Vlad, `i < n1 - length;` leads to trouble if _somehow_ `n1 < length`,  `i + length < n1;` does not have that trouble.